# Is the macOS Hardened Runtime a part of the OS SDK?

Tags: xcode, macos

So we're preparing for XCode updates for our application, as well as macOS SDK updates, and it's unclear to me if the used of the Hardened Runtime, required for notarization, is tied with which macOS SDK version you're using?

Where does the hardened runtime live, and how does a compiled application interact with it?  Unclear if it's via language runtime libs (and therefore compiler / XCode verson), SDK, or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hardened runtime is applied during the code signing process. You can build an application without it and then, using the `codesign` command, sign with hardened runtime from the command line

```
codesign --force --options runtime --deep --sign "Developer ID Application: COMPANYNAME" MYAPP.app
```

Note the `runtime` flag. The man page for `codesign` states for runtime:

> On macOS versions >= 10.14.0, opts signed processes into a hardened runtime environment which includes runtime code signing enforcement, library
>                 validation, hard, kill, and debugging restrictions.  These restrictions can be selectively relaxed via entitlements. Note: macOS versions older
>                 than 10.14.0 ignore the presence of this flag in the code signature.

Selecting the option for `hardened runtime` in Xcode, will apply the `runtime` argument when Xcode performs the signing process for you.

Comment: Thanks.  Key points that it's a part of the OS, it's not linked into the binary in the sense of "runtime library", nor requiring a particular version of XCode, but rather is enabled by the OS loader recognizing certain options in the application's signing.